# Creating a dropdown menu purely with HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I am very new to this so apologies in advance if this problem appears quite rudimentary! I appreciate all the help I can get on this as I am a keen learner :)

I have been trying to create two dropdown menu's that would appear as inline elements on the homepage of my company website. It appears that Javascript has been disabled for editing (as I have tried to previously use pre-made dropdown menus from Codepen).

I want users to simply click on the dropdown and then the option they click on will take them to that relevant part of the website.

This is the HTML I have created so far. I am hoping to keep this dropdown to HTML and CSS.

Thanks guys in advance! :)

```html
 <div class=" col-xs-12 cold-md-6">
    <select role="menu" id="dropdownMenuElement_10990" class="form-control input-lg " style> == $0
        <option value="/">Looking for a product?</option>
        <option value="/3dexperience">3DEXPERIENCE</option>
        <option value="/catia">CATIA</option>
        <option value="/enovia">ENOVIA</option>
        <option value="/delmia">DELMIA</option>
        <option value="/dymola">DYMOLA</option>
        <option value="/reqtify">REQTIFY</option>
        <option value="/controlbuild">CONTROLBUILD</option>
        <option value="/exalead">EXALEAD</option>
        <option value="/netvibes">NETVIBES</option>
        <option value="/master-3dgage">MASTER 3DGAGE</option>
        <option value="/verisurf">VERISURF</option>
        </select>
  
     
    </div>
```

Comment: so what was the issue?

Comment: You want to redirect on change of the select?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro correct. When the user selects the option from the dropdown, it will redirect them to that relevant part of the website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below will work. Here's a **[codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/jXEQNY)** with a working link (click **3dexperience**).

```html
<div class=" col-xs-12 cold-md-6">
    <select role="menu" id="dropdownMenuElement_10990" class="form-control input-lg" onchange="location = this.value;">
          <option value="/">Looking for a product?</option>
          <option value="/3dexperience">3DEXPERIENCE</option>
          <option value="/catia">CATIA</option>
          <option value="/enovia">ENOVIA</option>
          <option value="/delmia">DELMIA</option>
          <option value="/dymola">DYMOLA</option>
          <option value="/reqtify">REQTIFY</option>
          <option value="/controlbuild">CONTROLBUILD</option>
          <option value="/exalead">EXALEAD</option>
          <option value="/netvibes">NETVIBES</option>
          <option value="/master-3dgage">MASTER 3DGAGE</option>
          <option value="/verisurf">VERISURF</option>
        </select>     
    </div>
```

Comment: what is new in your answer please explain?

Comment: I added an `onchange` event to the `<select>`. Just look at the code and my codepen example. Please mark the answer correct if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @webfrogs this checks out! Thank you so much for being able to do this, much appreciated!

Comment: Sure thing. Anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Use on change `select` then scroll window to id of your div section that you want set the id of section as value of option

Using Jquery

```js
$('#selectBox').change(function() {   
   var selectedValue = $(this).val(); 
   var elem=$('#'+selectedValue)
   $('html, body').scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
   
});
```

```css
select{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" col-xs-12 cold-md-6">
    <select id="selectBox" role="menu" id="dropdownMenuElement_10990" class="form-control input-lg "> 
        <option value="/">Looking for a product?</option>
        <option value="3dexperience">3DEXPERIENCE</option>
        <option value="catia">CATIA</option>
        <option value="enovia">ENOVIA</option>
        <option value="delmia">DELMIA</option>
        <option value="dymola">DYMOLA</option>
        <option value="reqtify">REQTIFY</option>
        <option value="controlbuild">CONTROLBUILD</option>
        <option value="exalead">EXALEAD</option>
        <option value="netvibes">NETVIBES</option>
        <option value="master-3dgage">MASTER 3DGAGE</option>
        <option value="verisurf">VERISURF</option>
        </select>
  
     
    </div>
    
<div id="lookingFor">
<h1>lookingFor</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis diam mauris, at semper nulla dapibus vitae. Nulla at dignissim ex. Sed maximus tristique feugiat. Vivamus et congue mauris. Morbi consectetur tortor ut tristique viverra. Quisque ut iaculis purus, sit amet malesuada massa. Praesent at enim vel nisl luctus tincidunt. Aliquam condimentum placerat magna, eget tempus leo congue id. Duis metus ex, vulputate a ligula vel, congue volutpat elit. Nullam sit amet tortor tempor, lobortis diam vitae, finibus nisl. Aliquam vel odio eros. Phasellus commodo enim orci, ut elementum sem laoreet at. Donec tristique a ex quis viverra. Quisque at lorem nisl.
</p>
</div>
<div id="3dexperience">
<h1>3dexperience</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis diam mauris, at semper nulla dapibus vitae. Nulla at dignissim ex. Sed maximus tristique feugiat. Vivamus et congue mauris. Morbi consectetur tortor ut tristique viverra. Quisque ut iaculis purus, sit amet malesuada massa. Praesent at enim vel nisl luctus tincidunt. Aliquam condimentum placerat magna, eget tempus leo congue id. Duis metus ex, vulputate a ligula vel, congue volutpat elit. Nullam sit amet tortor tempor, lobortis diam vitae, finibus nisl. Aliquam vel odio eros. Phasellus commodo enim orci, ut elementum sem laoreet at. Donec tristique a ex quis viverra. Quisque at lorem nisl.
</p>
</div>
<div id="catia">
<h1>catia</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis diam mauris, at semper nulla dapibus vitae. Nulla at dignissim ex. Sed maximus tristique feugiat. Vivamus et congue mauris. Morbi consectetur tortor ut tristique viverra. Quisque ut iaculis purus, sit amet malesuada massa. Praesent at enim vel nisl luctus tincidunt. Aliquam condimentum placerat magna, eget tempus leo congue id. Duis metus ex, vulputate a ligula vel, congue volutpat elit. Nullam sit amet tortor tempor, lobortis diam vitae, finibus nisl. Aliquam vel odio eros. Phasellus commodo enim orci, ut elementum sem laoreet at. Donec tristique a ex quis viverra. Quisque at lorem nisl.
</p>
</div>
<div id="enovia">
<h1>enovia</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sagittis diam mauris, at semper nulla dapibus vitae. Nulla at dignissim ex. Sed maximus tristique feugiat. Vivamus et congue mauris. Morbi consectetur tortor ut tristique viverra. Quisque ut iaculis purus, sit amet malesuada massa. Praesent at enim vel nisl luctus tincidunt. Aliquam condimentum placerat magna, eget tempus leo congue id. Duis metus ex, vulputate a ligula vel, congue volutpat elit. Nullam sit amet tortor tempor, lobortis diam vitae, finibus nisl. Aliquam vel odio eros. Phasellus commodo enim orci, ut elementum sem laoreet at. Donec tristique a ex quis viverra. Quisque at lorem nisl.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using bootstrap and since you want an HTML and CSS solution only so then you should use the code provided from bootstrap documentation here:

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#potato">Potato</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#xxx">XXX</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#zzz">ZZZ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And let's say that when you click on Potato you want to get to the potato section of your website, all you have to do is to give the potato section an id similar to the href passed in the above link, and if the section is an external page you just pass the link on the page in the href of the dropdown item.

Comment: That's not what the question asked for.